# Recursively building a hierarchy of TreeNodes - almost there but not quite

Tags: json, recursion, treeview

I am trying to build a hierarchy of TreeNodes from a JSON structure.  Reading the file recursively work fine (i.e. Console.WriteLine produces the correct output), but I can't create the TreeNodes structure properly.

I pretty sure my problem has to do with the fact I am NOT passing in the correct TreeNode when I call the function recursively, but I don't know how to change the code.  I only want to create a new node when the JToken type is a string, but only call the function recursively if the JToken type is an array .....

```
// calling function
// ================
JArray geoscheme = (JArray)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(file));

TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode()
{
    Name = "RootNode"
};

foreach (JToken location in geoscheme)
{                  
    GetChildNodes(location, parentNode);
}

// recursive function - works except the treeview bits
// ===================================================

public void GetChildNodes(JToken location, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    foreach (JToken item in location)
    {
        if (item.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode()
            {
                Name = item.Value<string>()
            };

            parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);

            // Console.WriteLine(item.Value<string>()); 
        }

        if (item.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            GetChildNodes(item, parentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the JSON structure I use:

```
[
  [
    "World",
      [
        "Continents",
        [
          "Africa",
          [
            "Northern Africa",
            "Sub-Saharan Africa",
            [
              "Eastern Africa",
              "Central Africa",
              "Southern Africa",
              ....
```

Comment: Is that valid JSON? Doesn't look like it is to me.

Comment: JSON Lint likes it and the code works (I get the output I want).  My only problem is creating the treeview.